# Fitted Beta distribution always holds water. Can I force it not to?

Tags: fitting, curve-fitting, beta-distribution

I am trying to fit a beta distribution to election forecast data.
The ultimate purpose is determining with what probability the election will be decided by one vote (more on this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124043/beta-binomial-distribution-with-a-priori-alpha-and-beta-to-account-for-pro)).

My data is as follows:

```
0.517 0.59 0.55 0.528 0.496 0.51 0.55 0.54 0.57
```

I use the scipy `scipy.stats.beta.fit()` function, as [discussed here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68983/beta-distribution-fitting-in-scipy).

For my data I get:

$\alpha = 0.7469674643946238 $

$\beta = 1.7165349362225657 $

which leads to a sloping distribution with its maximum close to zero.

For most other artificial data I have tried, I get distributions which actually hold water. Obviously, for my case this is wrong (it may not be for others), but I would like to make certain that the **minima** of the distribution are close to 0 and 1 respectively, and the maximum is approximately in the range of my data points.

I had thought of fitting a normal distribution to my data, and a beta distribution to that - but that would be an approximation of an approximation. I'd rather do it all in one "step".

Comment: 16 decimal places for the parameter estimates when the data are to 2 d.p.!

Comment: I don't get your point. The distribution will still look the same if I round the parameters to fewer decimals.

Comment: That was just a quick initial reaction, but spurious precision often is a bad sign and encouraging better practices in reporting is surely consistent with the aims here. In terms of your question, something appears very wrong with your estimates, which imply a mean of about 0.303, which isn't even within the range of your data. At this point, the question is really whether you found a bug in the software or misapplied the software, and is possibly outside the scope of the forum. I see absolutely no point to fitting a normal first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the `scipy.stats.beta.fit` function is weird and undocumented. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329331/how-to-properly-fit-a-beta-distribution-in-python), what it does is fit a generalized beta distribution (i.e. a beta distribuction which has been shifted and stretched to be nonzero on an interval other than $[0,1]$) with max and min included as parameters. If you don't specify the max and min, then it will choose weird values instead of the standard zero and 1 (see the top answer to the linked question.) So it looks like you should try

```
scipy.stats.beta.fit(data, floc=0, fscale=1)
```

on your data. Unfortunately, I don't have access to it right now so can't try it, but the correct values should be $\alpha = 168$, $\beta = 144$. You can get them from [an online app here](http://www.wessa.net/rwasp_fitdistrbeta.wasp).

Comment: I actually discovered this independently in the mean time, but it's encouraging to also hear it from you, I was afraid I might just have "hacked" it.

Comment: And with such large values of the parameters, the normal approximation is essentially indistinguishable.

Comment: From a variety of starting points, R's `fitdistr` gives values for $\alpha$ between about 166 and 173 and for $\beta$ between about 142 and 148 (in each case the standard error is a bit under half the estimate). It looks like there's a reasonably broad range of values in the region of the values you give, with similar fits. The two estimates are very highly correlated.

Comment: Regarding the high correlation - their ratio seems to be pretty well determined (e.g. we can estimate the mean accurately), but their sum is not (we don't have such a good estimate of the variance).

Comment: so you're saying `scipy.stats.beta.fit` is noticeably not as good as R's `fitdistr`? Is that also fitting a beta distribution?

Comment: Stata program `betafit` from SSC with defaults gives $\alpha = 169, \beta =  145$, rounding to nearest integer, and so matching @Glen_b's  results.

Comment: TheChymera -- I don't see how you'd get that from what I said. I was confirming Flounderer's results, but indicating that other start values might give what read like different answers (as would different optimizers), but those fits may be almost identical. R's `fitdistr` will fit whatever you tell it to (the beta is one of the built-in densities, but you can supply a density function of your choice). I asked it to fit the usual two-parameter beta.